# How do I change the root folder of the Folder Browser object to a specific folder/path other than system folders?

Tags: c#, directory

This does not work:

```
fbFolderBrowser.RootFolder = @"C:\A Folder I Created\Test1\";
```

When the user clicks the button, I want to have the above folder selected.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How have you created variable `fbFolderBrowser`?

Comment: Your question does not match your description. You talk about setting the root in the title and code, but you are asking about setting the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `RootFolder` you need to set `SelectedPath` -

```
fbFolderBrowser.SelectedPath = @"C:\A Folder I Created\Test1\";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly:

```
fbFolderBrowser.InitialDirectory = @"C:\A Folder I Created\Test1\";
```